# how to get a reference to the specific v-model in form

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue2 and am trying to to get a reference to a model's value in a form to be passed to a method. I have:

```
<div v-for="n in maxLength">
    <input v-model='price.matrix_prices[n]' /><div @click="fillPrices(?)">set all to this price</div>
{{n}}</div>
```

The matrix_prices is a hash with specified values. Lets say someone fills in 8 in the input model, how would I get a reference so that `?` would be eight?

Comment: You're using `price.matrix_prices[n]` as the model, so that's the value you want to pass to `fillPrices`

Comment: yeah, so if the user enters 8 or some arbitrary value, just the 8 not whole matrix_prices. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to `n` in the function as below?

```
<div v-for="n in maxLength">
  <input v-model='price.matrix_prices[n]' />
  <div @click="fillPrices(n)">set all to this price
  </div>
  {{n}}
</div>
```

If yes write the function like this:

```
methods: {
  fillPrices(n) {
    var data = this.price.matrix_prices[n];
    //do something with the data
  }
}
```